# ungrouping a grouped pandas dataframe by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a `pandas_dataframe` like this.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'name':['A','A','B','C','B','B','C','C','C','A'],'ids':['M_1','M_1','K_1','K_1','K_1','K_1','G_1','G_1','G_1','K_1'],
            'no' :[1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1],'colors':['Red','black','green','blue','yellow','white','rose','pink','maroon','lightblue']})
```

The data frame after sorted by `name` and `ids` looks like this.

[image: Sorted dataframe]After grouping by name and ids, it looks like this.
[image: dataframe after grouping operation]
I want the final data frame with a new column and
ungrouped.
[image: Expecteddataframe]
I am new to this forum and yet to learn how to paste the outputs
obtained from jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `transform`

```
df['max_no'] = df.groupby(['name','ids'])['no'].transform('max')
df
Out[147]: 
  name  ids  no     colors  max_no
0    A  M_1   1        Red       2
1    A  M_1   2      black       2
2    B  K_1   1      green       3
3    C  K_1   2       blue       2
4    B  K_1   3     yellow       3
5    B  K_1   1      white       3
6    C  G_1   2       rose       4
7    C  G_1   3       pink       4
8    C  G_1   4     maroon       4
9    A  K_1   1  lightblue       1
```

Comment: Appreciate your fastest answer, great!!